# NSDateFormatter: How to Shorten Formatted Date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using an `NSDateFormatter` to format my date in SQLite table cell value.
The type of my cell is `datetime`, and the values I enter are like: "01.11.2011", "02.11.2012" (dd.MM.yyyy)

When I'm getting the data, I'm using an `NSDateFormatter` like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

And my output values are like this:

```
2011-11-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

How can I shorten this value as a date value only? Like `2011-11-01`?
And more, how can I change the places and separators in this value like `01.11.2011`?

Edit: My mistake, I didn't show how I got the values. Like this:

```
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 7)]];
```

Edit-2: I put a breakpoint and checked the coming value from this string, it's like 01.11.2011, as I entered the database.

Comment: Where are you getting the output values from? You haven't shown how you're *using* the formatter.

Comment: which sting  you are passing to dateformatter

Comment: I edited the question content.

Comment: @confeng that's how you get the NSDate object from a string. You can use the same dateFormatter to get a formatted date string by calling  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]

Comment: @Nevin, True, but my problem is that I want to order and stereotype values by this dates. Will I be able to use stringFromDate value for this? There's I'm suspicious.

Comment: @confeng Na, to sort use the NSDate object is better. You only need to get a formatted date in string for displaying purpose.

Comment: @Nevin well, then I try to use two values: one is string and to show, another is date and to sort. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty much correct. You didn't show how you get the output from the dateFormatter though. With the formatter format set to:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.mm.yyyy"];
NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This should assign formattedDate with

```
04.10.2011
```

Comment: The output in the question looks to me like what you get when logging the `NSDate` object directly. This is not affected by the formatter, the `stringFromDate` method in this answer must be used to get the formatted string.

Comment: True, that's why I said @confeng didn't show how she/he get the output from the dateFormatter.

Comment: It was a supporting comment, not criticism :)